# Error with gclient sync while getting the chromium code on Mac OS

Tags: macos, chromium

I'm trying to setup the chromium code following the [documentation](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code) on Mac OS X 10.9.2.

I could successfully fetch the code with command:

fetch --nohooks chromium --nosvn=True

but when I try to sync the projects with gclient sync command it's breaking in the middle of the process throwing the following OSError:

```
________ running '/usr/bin/python src/build/download_nacl_toolchains.py --no-arm-trusted --keep' in '/Volumes/NJHD/google'
Updating /Volumes/NJHD/google/src/native_client/toolchain/.tars/toolchain_mac_x86.tar.bz2
    from https://storage.googleapis.com/nativeclient-archive2/x86_toolchain/r12790/toolchain_mac_x86.tar.bz2.
.....................................................................................
|------------------------------------------------|
..................................................Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/build/download_nacl_toolchains.py", line 63, in <module>
    sys.exit(Main(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "src/build/download_nacl_toolchains.py", line 58, in Main
    download_toolchains.main(args)
  File "/Volumes/NJHD/google/src/native_client/build/download_toolchains.py", line 414, in main
    keep=options.keep, verbose=options.verbose):
  File "/Volumes/NJHD/google/src/native_client/build/download_toolchains.py", line 263, in SyncFlavor
    tar.Extract()
  File "/Volumes/NJHD/google/src/native_client/build/cygtar.py", line 313, in Extract
    self.tar.extract(m)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2084, in extract
    self._extract_member(tarinfo, os.path.join(path, tarinfo.name))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2168, in _extract_member
    self.makelink(tarinfo, targetpath)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2252, in makelink
    os.link(tarinfo._link_target, targetpath)
OSError: [Errno 45] Operation not supported
Error: Command /usr/bin/python src/build/download_nacl_toolchains.py --no-arm-trusted --keep returned non-zero exit status 1 in /Volumes/NJHD/google
Hook '/usr/bin/python src/build/download_nacl_toolchains.py --no-arm-trusted --keep' took 89.91 secs
```

It seems to me that it is complaining about os.link(tarinfo._link_target, target path), so I tried creating a link using that function which works fine.

Is there any other configuration that I need to take care of?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I placed the chromium project on an external hard disk as you did, and I got the same error.

Perhaps you should try the syncing stuff in your internal drive.

Haven't tried. Hope that help.